# Rules for substantive declination (without article)

Tags: single-word-request

I think that I know the mean rules to build substantive declination (without article) in german. I usually see leo.org when I have a doubt and I have found a surprise whith the substantive "das Kind".

What I want to do is declinate Kind in genitiv plural (when you don't use the article "der"), in leo.org you can see that it is "Kindern", but you can see that it's "Kinder" in the next page:

https://www.google.es/search?q=deklination+nomen+pdf+kindern&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYn8Ph49zhAhUImuAKHRhICqgQ_AUIDigB&biw=1317&bih=630#imgrc=Dn3YVbgw97qYoM:

I have two questions, the first one is which is the correct between the two forms before declarated. I think that I manage substantive declination when you use "bestimmte Artikel", but I have not found neither texts nor notes which explain about this when you use "unbestimmte Artikel" or simply you omit the article, so my second question is: do german language make difference between the substantive declination, with der, die, das,..., and without them?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It's *der Kinder* and *(einigen) Kindern*.

Comment: Danke! Do you know where I can consult grammar about the construction of substantive declination (cases indefinite article and no article)?

Comment: Please look up the **adjective declension**. Why? You want to know about nouns! Because article/pronoun, noun and adjective declension all depend on each other. It's simpler to look at the whole story first so you get a better feeling for the patterns.

Comment: I guess I understand adjective declension. I do not why but for adjectives, the declension differences between definite and indefinite article, and even when you do not use article. However I cannot get that information also for nouns.

Comment: It's the same system: exactly one part of the item needs the strong declension (multiple adjectives cound as one here), the others are either weak or mixed. It boggles my mind each time I think about it. Sorry. I'm glad I learned that through practice alone.

Comment: can you give me an example to compare my knowledge of adjectives to understand noun declension?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92659/discussion-between-janka-and-joseabp91).

Comment: What is "substantive declination"?

Comment: Nouns do not vary for definiteness. You are looking for rules that don't exist (or are trivial). Mind you, there are multiple classes of noun declension with different endings such as -er, -e, -n plurals, but that has nothing to do with articles.

Comment: Google does not show the same results to different people. Posting a link to a google search will bring unpredictable results to the people.

Comment: The mistake OP is referring to can is found in [this table](https://dict.leo.org/pages/flecttab/flectionTable.php?kvz=4dkrADn71HeCbYC86wSPgvtmz_-hDVHyRCkrUL_9hScDG0HPGhR9At5Xawuw-1TIkWxu1j49g2LkPIb_zhLO8hrGGfBQLsIUBu8dUIgtoqN0u8Zfm4MtkhxgGSRQPsKUxz79IG1bIseHHQBtmxKtFIsT6a0UzdJShl-695ANYgR&lp=ende&lang=en) on leo.org, which has *Kindern* as genitive plural (in the indefinite table, which should trivially be identical to the definite one).

Comment: Yes, it must be a mistake from leo.org. Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In German there the declination of a noun depends only on the number (singular or plural) and on the grammatical case (nominative, genitive, dative or accusative). It **NEVER** depends on the definiteness (definite or indefinte). Also the declination of the German noun *das Kind* does not depend on the definiteness.

### Singular

- **Nominativ**

  - bestimmt

    > **Das Kind** schläft.
  - unbestimmt

    > **Ein Kind** schläft.
- **Genitiv**

  - bestimmt

    > *Objekt:* Die Mitschüler gedenken **des Kindes.**
    >   *Attribut:* Die Schuhe **des Kindes** sind rot.
  - unbestimmt

    > *Objekt:* Die Mitschüler gedenken **eines Kindes.**
    >   *Attribut:* Die Schuhe **eines Kindes** sind rot.

  Also possible, mainly in colloquial speech: *des/eines Kinds*
- **Dativ**

  - bestimmt

    > Die Schuhe gehören **dem Kind.**
  - unbestimmt

    > Die Schuhe gehören **einem Kind.**

  In old texts you also will find: *dem/einem Kinde,* but it's outdated today
- **Akkusativ**

  - bestimmt

    > Ich sehe **das Kind.**
  - unbestimmt

    > Ich sehe **ein Kind.**

### Plural

- **Nominativ**

  - bestimmt

    > **Die Kinder** schlafen.
  - unbestimmt

    > **Kinder** schlafen.
- **Genitiv**

  - bestimmt

    > *Objekt:* Die Mitschüler gedenken **der Kinder.**
    >   *Attribut:* Die Schuhe **der Kinder** sind rot.
  - unbestimmt

    > *Objekt:* Die Mitschüler gedenken **der Kinder.**
    >   *Attribut:* Die Schuhe **der Kinder** sind rot.
- **Dativ**

  - bestimmt

    > Die Schuhe gehören **den Kindern.**
  - unbestimmt

    > Die Schuhe gehören **Kindern.**
- **Akkusativ**

  - bestimmt

    > Ich sehe **die Kinder.**
  - unbestimmt

    > Ich sehe **Kinder.**

Comment: Dankeschön!! You typed the same for bestimmt and unbestimmt case in genitiv plural case. But I understand by your explanation that both are Kinder.

Comment: By the way, do you know any good website to look at the conjutation of verbs, declination of adjectives, and these things? Until now, I was using leo.org, but it lies about the importance about the definiteness when you want to declinate a noun.

Comment: @joseabp91: Try Wiktionary: [»Kind« on Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Kind)

Comment: Alles Klar, dankeschön!